# Random number guessing game -- cant figure it out, even when i set the number as 7 and guess 7 it says its wrong. Also problem with function calling

Tags: python

```
def guessNum():
    guess = input("guess a number between 1 and 10:  ")
    guesses = 3
    
    randomNum = 7
        
    while guess != randomNum:
        guesses -=1 
        print("wrong," + str(guesses) + "guesses left")
        guess = input("guess again  ")
        if guesses <= 1:
            print("You lose")
            break
        if guess == randomNum:
            print("You win")
            break
        
    
            
print guessNum()
```

so im having issues with it saying false when its correct. Also when I create a function, it only executes if I give it an input. why does it require an input? cant it have 0 or guessnum(1) and put a random variable when defining it, ie def guessnum(num):

Comment: For one thing, if you are using Python3, you need to convert the input to an number: `guess = int(input("guess a number between 1 and 10:  "))`

Comment: Make sure your move your if(guess == random) statement to the top of your while loop

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you input something, it isn't normally an integer. Instead, it's a string. Hence, all you have to do is add the line `guess = int(guess)` right after the user guesses again.